# Node Wrangler and v2.76

Tags: installation

I can not get node wrangler addon to install in 2.76b.  Anybody else have the same issue, or is it just me?  I will continue trying.

Comment: Working here. It's shipped with blender, so there is no need for an installation. Simply go to *User Preferences > Add-ons > Nodes* and enable it.

Comment: I thought that might be the case but could not find any references to the fact.  Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help :)